# php replace string regex

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have a incoming value of:

"My Store Name - Tag - 30BG04S13G-2DST2 my item - My Store Name"

```
set to :<?php echo $name; ?>
```

I'm trying to create a regex that will strip out the first part of the string so it looks like this:

"30BG04S13G-2DST2 my item - My Store Name"

I just need to strip this: "My Store Name - Tag - " off of the front

Comment: This might help you out: https://txt2re.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your string will always begin with "My Store Name - Tag - ", then you can use the following via the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$input = preg_replace("^My Store Name - Tag - ", "", $input);
```

The expression itself simply uses the `^` character to indicate the start of the string, followed by the values you intend to strip out).